# One-Jar FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, onejar

I have une Java application, and I use in it the openCv(opencv_java259.jar).
It work correcly in Eclipse.
For pack the application in a executable .jar file, I use [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=quickstart) (Command Line Approch) but it don't work correctly and I have this errors:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tool> jar -cvfm ../one-jar.jar boot-manifest.mf .java.io.FileNotFoundException: boot-manifest.mf 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:171)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

I have done these steps :

- I have create from Eclipse an runnable .jar file : right clik on the project-->Export--->Runnable Jar File
- I Create a working directory "Tool" contains directories main and lib
- Copy my main application jar file (create on step 1) into root/main (named MyApplication.jar) and library dependencies into root/lib (the opencv_java259.jar)
- I have Unjar the one-jar-boot-0.97.jar file into the root directory
- Edit the boot-manifest.mf :

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
>
> Created-By: One-Jar 0.97 Ant taskdef
>
> One-Jar-Main-Class: main.MyApplication
>
> Main-Class: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot

But I have the errors when i execute the command line:

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tool> jar -cvfm ../one-jar.jar boot-manifest.mf .

Have you suggestions? Thanks for all.

Comment: With the given command line `jar -cvfm ../one-jar.jar boot-manifest.mf .` the file `boot-manifest.mf` must be in the current directory where `jar` is executed. Maybe it is in `META-INF` instead?

Comment: Where I do the command i have META-INF

Comment: Don't Have suggestions for me? Help please....I'm two days with this problem and I don't have a solution.

Comment: I have solve it changed the command line jar -cvfm ../one-jar.jar META-INF/manifest.mf .  Now i have another problem: Exception in "main" java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException : main.MyApplication

Comment: One-Jar now compile but the when the .jar start i have the problem of the load openCV...this non work correctly!